# Using trigger in one table and updating other table

Tags: sql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.YourTrigger
ON a
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT UPDATE(name)
RETURN

UPDATE d
set upload = 1
FROM d
END
```

This is the code, but it's not working the way i want it. in this case its updating my upload field from Table (d) when every any record change in table (a) .
i want upload field in table (d) to be change only when (name field) change in Table (a).

Comment: Is there any relationship between table a and table d?

Comment: Forgot to mention yes these tables have a relationship of primary and foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the special `Inserted` and `Deleted` tables inside a trigger to identify which rows have been affected. For an update trigger, `Deleted` contains the "before" version of the rows and `Inserted` contains the "after" version of the rows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.YourTrigger
ON a
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(name)
        UPDATE d
            set upload = 1
            FROM Inserted i
                INNER JOIN Deleted de
                    ON i.EmpId= de.EmpId
                INNER JOIN d
                    ON i.EmpId= d.RecId
            WHERE i.name <> de.name
END
```

Comment: i am very new to sql. if you can explain me please. what is (de) and (i)

Comment: `de` and `i` are aliases for the `Deleted` and `Inserted` tables. It's just a short-hand way of referring to the table names in the query.

Comment: Thanks, i am not deleting any data from any table. its like if user change any information in one table then second table one of the field will be 1. so behalf of 1 or 0 later on can be deiced if data need to update in master database or not. sry my English is not that great.

Comment: @user643092: I understood that you're not deleting data. The `Deleted` table is used here because it contains the "before" version of the rows that were impacted by your update statement.

Comment: Thanks so much. its work. one more question. if i have more than one field , like first name and last name.

Comment: @user643092: Then use OR in both the IF and the WHERE clause: `IF UPDATE(firstname) OR UPDATE(lastname) ... WHERE I.firstname <> de.firstname OR I.lastname <> de.lastname`

Comment: thanks you Joe. how can i improve my skill quicker . is there any book which can help. i really need to improve my self

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure updateTrigger, Line 17
Invalid column name 'PrimaryKey'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure updateTrigger, Line 17
Invalid column name 'PrimaryKey'.  This error is showing

Comment: @user643092: `PrimaryKey` was just a dummy placeholder. You should substitute the name of your real primary key column. The same holds true for `ForeignKey`.

Comment: @user643092: For a beginning T-SQL book, I'd recommend [this](http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-T-SQL-Fundamentals-PRO-Developer/dp/0735626014/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1299184587&sr=8-3).

Comment: just come to find out only table a has a primary key not the table d

Comment: @user643092: That's OK as long as one of the columns in table d references table a's primary key as a foreign key.

Comment: in table a EmpID and table d RecID

Comment: @user643092: I'll update my answer with these column names. I sure hope this answer gets accepted (click on the outlined check mark next to the answer) after all this work. :-)

Comment: this code is working , but its change table d (field upload) when any field data change in table a. – user643092 1 min ago edit

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do it a little cleaner and simple since you are only going to update if name is updated...

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.YourTrigger
ON a
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF UPDATE(name)
BEGIN
UPDATE d
set upload = 1
FROM d
END
ELSE
BEGIN
       --HERE GOES CODE
END
END
```

Comment: actually i have 15 fields in Table (a) but if Three of them update, then table (d) upload field get the value of 1 other wise its 0 by default

Comment: i Forgot to mention yes these tables have a relationship of primary and foreign key

Comment: just add IF UPDATE(name) AND UPDATE(field2) and UPDATE(field3) if you need to do something when that condition does not work just add an ELSE statement

Comment: this code is working , but its change table d (field upload) when any field data change in table a.